# Cannot mount - busted superblock?

Tags: mount

I was running a debian server which basically died on its backside this morning. Eventually I moved to a new server i was prepping up anyway (running CentOS) i had some backups but the rest was on the flaky disk of the old server.

So i got the host to attach it to my new server I just needed the mysql files (.myd) etc from that disk as i didn't have backups of some databases.

all other partitions mount ok I am having problems with 1 and its the one ( i think) that has the data i need

When i run the following command

```
mount /dev/sdb3 /media/3
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

I have tried running fsck /dev/sdb3 and i get the below

```
fsck /dev/sdb3
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb3

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

So i did a bit of digging and even tried this

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sdb3 | grep superblock
dumpe2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Fully out of ideas , can anyone help me with this or is it time to write off the data loss

Comment: Whatever the result of this is, it's clearly time for a better backup system.

Comment: If the data is worth more than $89 or so, you could try spinrite, which is likely the only thing that could restore the disk on the cheap.  http://grc.com.

Comment: What does `/etc/fstab` contain (on the old server) and what is the output of `fdisk -l`?